# How can I create subfacet in xhtml?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, html-table, facet

I am developing a complex table with `nodes` and many `rows` by `node`. I would like add `f:facet`s to `f:facet` for my table.

I have this.

[image]

I would like this.

[image]

```
<h:form id="formPartes">
    <h:panelGroup id="pgPartes">
        <p:treeTable id="tablaPartes" class=" validate tablaNormal" style="border:none;" value="#{estrategiaBean.nodoProyecto}" var="parte">
            <p:column headerText="Nombre">
                <h:outputText value="#{parte.nombre}" />
                <h:panelGroup id="agregarParteHija#{generalBean.unir(parte.nombre)}">
                    <h:commandLink action="#{estrategiaBean.cargarNuevaParte(parte)}">
                        <f:ajax render=":formNuevaParte:pgNuevaParte" execute="agregarParteHija#{generalBean.unir(parte.nombre)}"/>
                        <i class="material-icons small">add</i>
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Ts...">
                <ui:repeat value="#{estrategiaBean.funcionesDeParte(parte)}" var="atributo">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{atributo.obtLista('TAM_Ciclo')}" var="atributo3">
                                    <th class="ui-state-default">
                                        #{atributo3.atributo}
                                    </th>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{atributo.obtLista('TAM_Ciclo')}" var="atributo3">
                                    <td>
                                        <h:inputText value="#{atributo3.valor}"/>
                                    </td>
                                </ui:repeat>  
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
    <h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Please, help me with  `xhtml` code.

Comment: Tried column groups like in the datatable? Not sure if it works, just a guess